# Dropdown is not set with its ng-model Value in Edit-Profile Case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My Dropdown is not set with its `ng-model` Value in Edit-Profile Case

> Here is my Controller.js method which calls service.js method and get data from database in Json format

```
function CountryList() {
    var getUserData = crudAJService.CountryList();  // calls Service method
    getUserData.then(function (response) {
        $scope.countryList = response.data;
    }, function () {
        console.log("Can't read Country data");
    });
```

I get countryList properly and html is rendered as expected (as I expect)

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="country" required="" ng-model="countryid" 
ng-options="option.Value as option.Text for option in countryList" ng-change="GetSelectedState(countryid)">
  <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Choose Country</option>
  <option value="1" label="India">India</option>
  <option value="2" label="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="3" label="China">China</option>
  <option value="4" label="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="5" label="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="6" label="koria">koria</option>
  <option value="7" label="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
</select>
```

There is also `ng-change` Method for getting state from Db with respect to countryId (Cascading-Dropdown) which is also fetched smoothly and rendered properly.

but in Edit Profile case my dropdown is not set on `ng-model` value.?(not set selected value)..

if I bind `{{countryid}}` than it is also get proper result in my form(for testing purpose).

> Here is my `EditUser()` method which is called when Edit button pressed from gridView.

```
$scope.EditUser = function (user) {
        var getUserData = crudAJService.getUser(user.UserID);
        getUserData.then(function (_user) {
        CountryList();            //this method is mention above.
        $scope.user = _user.data;
        $scope.firstName = user.FirstName;
        $scope.lastName = user.LastName;
        $scope.countryid = user.CountryID;
        Blah.. Blah.. So on
    }, function () {
                alert('Error in getting User records');
        });
```

I think I had given all the necessary information with code. but still if You want any info plz tell me.

**UPDATE**

As you Suggest I make an object for `ng-model` and than I changed `HTML` Like this

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" required="" ng-model="countryModel" ng-options="countryModel.Value as countryModel.Text for countryModel in countryList" ng-change="GetSelectedState(countryModel.Value)">
```

now my controller.js `EditUser()` method is Looks Like this Image ..

[image] (See Image.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` should be an object with two properties `Value` and `Text`. While `ng-option` is an array of objects. So in your case your `countryList` is like this:

```
$scope.countryList = [{Value: 1, Text: "India"}, {Value: 2, Text: "USA"}]
```

So `countryid` must be an object like this:

```
$scope.countryid = {Value: 1, Text: "India"}
```

**UPDATE**
If you only have country value then you can use this to build 'countryId' object:

```
let selectedId = 1;
$scope.countryId = $scope.countryList.filter(function (country) { 
                    return country.Value == selectedId; 
                })[0];
```

Your `HTML` for `select` element will then become like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" required="" ng-model="countryModel" ng-options="countryOpt as countryOpt.Text for countryOpt in countryList" ng-change="GetSelectedState(countryModel.Value)">
```

Comment: Thanx for clear my concept now I change ng-model ='countryModel' which is combination of {CountryID & CountryName} and ng-change=''GetState(countryModel.Value). But I have to make my countryModel object Manually from my [_user.data] Json as you mention how do I make it .?

Comment: I have updated answer. If problem is still not solved then please create a JsFiddle or Plunker,

Comment: shoaib happy .?.:)